# Connection refused when using HttpURLConnection in Java

Tags: java, wamp, httpurlconnection

I'm using a WAMP server on localhost and I have a small Java software that gets a response from a PHP file. I get the error below when I try to get the InputStream from the HttpURLConnection object (also when I try to get the responseCode or the responseMessage...). Help me please.

Error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:211)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:308)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:326)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1202)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1138)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1032)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:966)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1546)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1474)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:480)
    at javaapplication1.JavaApplication1.main(JavaApplication1.java:28)
C:\Users\Amine\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
```

Java code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, IOException 
{
    URL url = new URL("http://localhost/test/test.php");
    HttpURLConnection con  = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    System.out.println(con.getResponseCode());
}
```

PHP script (C:\wamp\www\test\test.php):

```
<?php echo "Hello world"; ?>
```

Comment: Please post all text as text, copy there the exception instead of posting an image of it. Did you try visiting that url with your browser? what do you get?

Comment: When i visit that url with my browser i get a normal response (i mean that i get the Hello world message)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All right, i have fixed the problem, it was with the wamp server.
i deleted it then i installed it again. and it works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Check your firewall settings.

It looks like connection to localhost:80 is allowed for browser, but disabled for your java app.

Comment: I get the same problem after turning the firewall off

Comment: I think that the problem is on wamp, because when i tried a different link (www.google.com) it's worked well